# Need Help with SQL Subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, subquery

I am trying to write a query that will return all orders that only have a Subscription included.  It is easy enough to write a query that includes all Orders with Subscriptions, another that includes all orders without a Subscription and then compare them with an unmatched query.

But I don't want to have to store Queries in my Access database, I prefer to have it all in my ASP code, and I can't get this to work with just one complex query.

Here are samples of what works if I store them:

```
Query1

SELECT tblOrders.OrderID, tblOrderItems.ProductID
FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblOrderItems ON tblOrders.OrderID = tblOrderItems.OrderID
WHERE ((Not ((tblOrderItems.ProductID)>=12 And (tblOrderItems.ProductID)<=15)));

Query2

SELECT tblOrders.OrderID, tblOrderItems.ProductID
FROM tblOrders INNER JOIN tblOrderItems ON tblOrders.OrderID = tblOrderItems.OrderID
WHERE ((((tblOrderItems.ProductID)>=12 And (tblOrderItems.ProductID)<=15)));

Query3

SELECT Query2.OrderID, Query2.ProductID
FROM Query2 LEFT JOIN Query1 ON Query2.OrderID = Query1.OrderID
WHERE (((Query1.OrderID) Is Null));
```

So, my question is 'how do I write Query3 so that it doesn't refer to Query1 or Query2?'
or, am I missing some other way do do this?

Thanks,
Pete
peteaugello@verizon.net

Comment: Using Query1 and Query2 as subquery table doesn't work?

ie:
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table1) t1 JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2) t2 USING(id)

Comment: Thanks, Slokun, but no: at least I can't get the joins to work.

Comment: Can you please give us table definitions (or examples) and explain what exactly you want in result set?

Comment: I'll be glad to give full details if you really want them, but briefly, I have tblProducts for my, well, products; tblOrders -- one record for each Order -- and tblOrderItems with a record for each Item in an Order.  tblOrderItems has the OrderID and ProductID, and and INNER JOIN gives me all of the Products for an Order.
Some of my Products are Subscriptions, which ship separately.  I need to find Orders that ONLY have subscriptions and nothing else, so I can mark them as shipped.
If you need more, please just let me know.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assumptions

- ProductID between 12 and 15 refers to
  subscriptions.
- You are looking for all orders with
  only subscriptions and no other
  product types.

How about something like this:

```
SELECT O.OrderID, TOI.ProductID
FROM tblOrders O
      INNER JOIN tblOrderItems TOI ON (O.OrderID = TOI.OrderID)
WHERE (TOI.ProductID between 12 and 15) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM tblOrderItems TOI2
                  WHERE (NOT TOI2.ProductID between 12 and 15) AND
                        (TOI2.OrderID=O.OrderID)
                 )
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  All of your assumptions are correct -- the problem is that tblOrders doesn't contain ProductID, I need to JOIN to tblOrderItems here.

Comment: oops. got the table wrong in the exists clause. I think I have it fixed now.

Comment: John: Sorry, but I'm still confused.  What is this:
    SELECT * 
                  FROM tblOrderItems TOI
                  WHERE (NOT TOI.ProductID between 12 and 15)
                        (TOI.OrderID=tblOrders.OrderID)

Shouldn't that part be able to stand along?  I feel link it's missing a keyword between the )( if you know what I mean. Doesn't there need to be a JOIN there?

Thanks again.
Pete

Comment: John -- that's it!  I guess I was having trouble with the AS clauses (and I see you left that keyword out -- I didn't know you could do that!)
Thanks for all your help.

Comment: An upvote or accepting my answer is all the thanks required. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to worry about having a join, here is a way to do it with a pivot table.

```
     select OrderID, 
     sum(case productID between 12 and 15 then 1 else 0 end) HAS_SUBSCRIPTION,
     sum(case productID between 12 and 15 then 0 else 1 end) HAS_OTHER
     FROM tblOrderItems
     GROUP BY OrderID
     HAVING HAS_SUBSCRIPTION > 0 and HAS_OTHER = 0;
```